# Reading valid rsyslog configurations from /etc/rsyslog.d/project.conf drops syntax errors?

Tags: rsyslog

I have a few lines of configurations that I need in my rsyslgog.

```
if $programname == 'project' then /var/log/file.log
```

When added to the end of the main rsyslog configuration file, /etc/rsyslog.conf, this configuration appears to be valid and functional.
However, when using the rsyslog.d directory I get a syntax error.

```
error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/project.conf, on or before line 2: syntax error on token '==' [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
```

Is there anything in the main config that has to be parsed in advance, or is this a bug that should be reported to Fedora 27 developers?

Answer (score 1):

As rsyslog author, I would assume that there is some include right in front of it that somehow renders your (valid) construct invalid. Red Hat unfortunately tends to stick to obsolete legacy format, and things like these can easily happen when this is used (after all, this was why we obsoleted it).

To hunt this down, I would check the config include that is included immediately in front of your own. If included via wildcards, the include order is sorted by filename.

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my bad. The configuration for my rsyslog config file was rewritten by my installer bash script, and that interpreted the $ sign as variable within the string. I should have double-checked the correctness of my config file.